# Re-deploying Azure RM template to a different resource group/location

Tags: azure, templates, deployment

I would like to create a resource group with couple of virtual machines in it in West US. After that I can download the template that describes this configuration. How do I use it to deploy this configuration to East US? The template includes things like public IP addresses that Azure assigns at creation. If I just try to deploy the template to East US and in a new resource group it fails with "Deployment template validation failed: 'Circular dependency detected on resource: '/subscriptions/da98df59-9115-4751-bc96-06d80c1fe88e/resourceGroups/VNet-East-US/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/ubuntu01342'. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template... for usage details.'. (Code: InvalidTemplate)"

I think the template has to be edited before it can be used to deploy the resources to a different region. Unfortunately I was not able to find any information on how to do it (what to remove and what to leave in place) . I think you need to "sysprep" it just like you try to generalize a VM image unfortunately I cannot find information how to do it.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Refr the below article to Customize the template:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-export-template#customize-the-template

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this article. 

I am aware you can use parameters to customize the template but when you have multiple resources and you edit the JSON by hand you can easily make a mistake or miss a setting that needs to be converted into a parameter.

I was hoping there was a better (automatic) way to convert a concrete template into a more generalized one that can be re-used.

Answer (score 0):

I have created several ARM templates. Sometimes I just create something with the portal and then I export de JSon definition. Export, as with many auto-generated stuff needs a cleanup before it can be really re-used.

It takes some time but is doable and recommended. Right now I almost never deploy something straight from the portal as I prefer to have a definition to recreate an environment every time I need it.

The steps I apply are:

- Remove everything that it's not really necessary. Some resources are created with default values simply because Azure creates them but you don't need.
- Parametrize everything that depends on your deployment, VM size, VNET...

I recommend the https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates project to see live examples about how templates are created. Another tool that helped me a lot learning this ARM stuff it's Visual Studio 2017. It includes a template to create ARM projects. There you have a nice visualization for the JSon template and a way to insert blank resources to fully customize them.

Finally you will rely a lot on the MS documentation for each resource i.e. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/networkinterfaces notice how URL include a base part and then the template namespace for each resource.

From your particular example it looks like a reference to an already created resource is causing an issue.

For instance when working with location I use something like

```
"location": "[resourceGroup().location]"
```

to constrain the whole template to the current deployment location or

```
"location": "[parameters('location')]"
```

if I need to specify something different

Hope that helps!